# Attribute and props are not updating after state mutation vue js 3 composition api

Tags: vuejs3

**Child Component**

```html
<template>
    <div class="confirmation" v-bind="attrs['class']">
        <h1>{{ props.message ?? "Are you sure?" }}</h1>
        <button @click="props.yesClick">Yes</button>
        <button @click="props.noClick">No</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useAttrs, watch } from '@vue/runtime-core'
const attrs = useAttrs();
const props = defineProps(['yesClick', 'noClick', 'message'])
console.log(props, 'props')
console.log(attrs['message'], 'attrs')
</script>

<script>
export default {
    inheritAttrs: false,
}
</script>
```

**Parent Component**

```html
<template>
    <div :id="props.id" class="vebo__modal">
        <div class="overlay d-none" @click="toggle" ref="overlay">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <component :is="ContentComponent" ref="contentTarget" v-bind="{...childAttributes.value}"></component>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <slot />
</template>

<script setup>
import { provide, shallowRef, watch, ref } from "@vue/runtime-core";

const ContentComponent = shallowRef();
const contentTarget = ref(null);
const overlay = ref(null);
const childAttributes = ref({
    class: 'center',
    message: 'hello world'
});

const options = ref({
    staticBackdrop: false,
})
const props = defineProps({
    id: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        default: "vebo__modal--container",
    },
});

watch(childAttributes, () => {
    console.log(childAttributes.value, 'watch')
})

/**
 * This method will make new instance of the component that passed in as parameter and show it
 *
 * @param {Component} content
 * @param {Object} attr
 */
function show(content, attr = null) {
    childAttributes.value = attr
    ContentComponent.value = content
    overlay.value.classList.remove('d-none');
    overlay.value.classList.add('d-flex');
}

/**
 * This method will hide the modal
 *
 */
function hide() {
    overlay.value.classList.add('d-none');
    overlay.value.classList.remove('d-flex');
}

provide('modal', {
    show,
    hide,
    options,
})
</script>
```

***I am passing a component and an object in show method as parameters.
Then updating the childAttributes ref with the passed attr parameter which should re-render the component is what I am guessing. Then binding the parameter on dynamic component using v-bind. My problem is I am not getting any parameter as props or attribute in my child component. My child component is showing all HTML fine but the attributes are not updating And I have checked with watch and the state is updating on parent component just fine***

Answer (score 0):

You should remove "props." from your templates.

By using `defineProps` the compiler allows you to reference props directly in the template without referring to the parent `props` object.

You can even just do `defineProps({ someProp: String })` without creating a `props` variable if you are only using them in the template.

However if you want to reference the `props` in the script you'll need to reference the props object e.g. `console.log(props.message);`